# c++ global variable was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, extern

I am new to C++. I am trying to modify a very complex video codec code as part of my final year school project. This is my code:

This is the header file in which I have declared three extern variables:
yuv.h

```
#include <vector>
namespace X265_NS 
{
extern int frameNumber;
extern int frameSize;
extern std::vector<int>numbers;

class YUVInput : public InputFile, public Thread
{
protected:

// some more variables

public:

// more variables and function declarations

};
}
```

This is the first file that uses these extern variables:
yuv.cpp

```
#include "yuv.h"
//more includes
#include <vector>

using namespace X265_NS;
int frameNumber;
int frameSize;
std::vector<int>numbers;

// some stuff and function calls
// here I use my extern variables in a function

frameNumber = readCount.get();
frameSize = ceil((double)height / 32) * ceil((double)width / 32);

//more stuff

bool YUVInput::populateFrameQueue()
{
   if(read<1)
             {
                  ifstream file("/home/abu-bakr/bin/test.txt");
                  int number;
                  while (file >> number)
                           numbers.push_back(number);
             }
}

// more stuff
```

This is the second class where I am using these extern variables:

analysis.cpp

```
#include "yuv.h"
#include <vector>
....
using namespace X265_NS;

// some stuff

// its in a function and only place where I am using these variables
int qp_ctu = numbers.at((ctu.m_cuAddr + 1) + (frameSize*(frameNumber - 1)));

// more stuff
```

I want to know:

- Is it the right place for declaration of my extern variables in yuv.h
  file?
- If I define these variables in both cpp files, "already defined"
  error is generated. If I define them in only one class, "unresolved
  external symbol" error comes in the other class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your yuv.cpp

```
using namespace X265_NS;
int frameNumber;
int frameSize;
```

These definitions are of `::frameNumber` and `::frameSize`, which are distinct from `X265_NS::frameNumber` and `X265_NS::frameSize`.

Change the above to

```
namespace X265_NS {
    int frameNumber;
    int frameSize;
}

using namespace X265_NS;    // for subsequent code that uses those variables
```

or to

```
int X265_NS::frameNumber;
int X265_NS::frameSize;

using namespace X265_NS;    // for subsequent code that uses those variables
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
There are still errors:
How can I define vector in my cpp files as "1 unresolved extern" variable error is generating.
Secondly as you told me to use above solution in subsequent classes that uses these variables, but this is producing "already defined error".

Thanks again for your help

Comment: I didn't suggest using the above solution in "subsequent classes" - by which I assume you mean that you're replicating the definition in multiple compilation units.   There is the "one-definition rule" in C++.  Which means, in this case, that you can't define your variables more than once IN THE WHOLE PROGRAM.

Comment: When I only declare these variables in yuv.cpp and don't declare these variables in analysis then "undeclared identifier error" is producing.
Please tell me how to define vector in cpp files too.